# Options menu not appearing low enough in Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In my Android app, the triple-dot button in the upper right on my toolbar view brings down options as defined in the menu XML file.

However the options are appearing *over* the triple dot (as in, overlapping it entirely), while I normally would expect it to appear below the triple dot. What might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the menu to appear over the triple dot icon is the standard way the menus are shown.

Look at almost any app with a standard menu icon. In fact, you can look at the [Material Design spec for menus](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage), and you will see that they are meant to cover the overflow icon (the triple dot).

Comment: I must be wearing orthopedic shoes, because I stand corrected. For some reason I had thought it appeared below! Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!